# Symfony2 app/console on a project copy

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, console

I have a Symfony2 project setup in /var/www.

Because I want different users working on the same project, I copied this project to their directory and changed the name of the database for example. I did that so they can test their changes on the server rather than installing wamp locally on their machine. Those changes will then be committed via svn/git.

However, the problem I am facing now is:
Because I copied the Symfony2 project to their own directory (e.g. home\mike), the user or I can not execute a php app/console command, because it is still refering to the one in /var/www.
So for example, when I do:

```
    sudo php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

This command will be executed on /var/www/Symfony rather than on home\mike\Symfony

How can I refer it to his own directory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to manually clear cache in your new project path.

Then, check this article, about migrating project: [How to override Symfony's Default Directory Structure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Deleting the cache in dev an prod has worked!

Answer (score 0):

Each project has it is own structure and the command.
If you have symfony on www you must have the console file under app